# react redux Object is not a function

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm trying to learn redux and so far it goes smoothly after I learnt how mapStateToProps and mapDispatchToProps works but I occur problem I dont understand.

before I implemented connect everything worked but after I tried to connect function with dispatch it shows

> Object(...) is not a function

```
function PlaneList(props, fakedata) {

  const addPlane = (e) => {
    if (e.target.checked) {
      props.AddSignedPlane(e.target.id)
    }
  }
  return (
    <Table className={props.tableNoPadding}>
      <TableHead className={props.tableBackground}>
        <TableRow>
          <StyledTableCell>
            <Checkbox disabled />
          </StyledTableCell>
          <StyledTableCell>Plane ID</StyledTableCell>
          <StyledTableCell>Wings </StyledTableCell>
        </TableRow>
      </TableHead>
    </Table>
  );
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    AddSignedPlanes: plane=> dispatch(AddSignedPlanes(plane))
  }
}

export default connect(null ,mapDispatchToProps)(PlaneList)
```

*
before i just exported it as a export default function PlaneList and everything worked
*

error is in my dashboard:

```
<div>{PlaneList(classes, fakeData)}</div>
```

EDIT:
I import it like this to dashboard:

```
import PlaneList from "./PlaneList";
```

and my Dashboard in big short:

```
class Dashboard extends Component {

render(){
  return(
  <main>
    .....
    <div>{PlaneList(classes, fakeData)}</div>
   </main>
  )
 }
}
```

Comment: Why do you not to formalize `PlaneList` as a general functional react component? Try this, and also give us more details about error togather with line  where it fired

Comment: but PlaneList is functional component, isn't it? or what do you mean? plus added code to show where is error

Comment: I think connect returns an object instead of a function so you'll probably have to render it as `<PlaneList />` instead of calling it as a function `PlaneList(...)`

Comment: @wmik yeah I thought so too but wasn't sure

Comment: @jacki you can always `console.log` whenever you need to inspect something.